# win7 dynamic disk set

Tags: windows-7, dynamic-disk, mirroring

I have 3 disk set up where disk1 is OS boot drive. disk2 & disk3 is a dynamic mirror. 
what happens if my boot drive is corrupted ? can I just bring the dynamic set to another machine ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, dynamic disks are portable. The volume information that tracks the dynamic nature of these volumes is appended to the end of the actual disks. So long as you have the full mirror-set, they should be visible in another Win7 system.

Answer (score 1):

I can verify whay SysAdmin1138 states is true, I have actually DONE and experienced this.  I have reinstalled windows on my boot drive

You may end up having to go into Run>diskmgmt.msc and doing something like "import foreign disk" or something similar if it doesnt automatically load the drives for you.

I believe or something similar (my memory is a bit rusty on whether I had to do that with the mirror or with a stripe).  Also it may or may not try to rebuild the second drive as a mirror.